# Asyncio Streams automatically restarts to read data even after writer.close() is run

Tags: python, tcp, stream, python-asyncio

I followed the tutorial in https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html to read data from a sensor (TCP protocol, PC as the server):

```
import datetime
import asyncio
import socket

async def connect_to_sq():
      _ip = "0.0.0.0"
      _port = 45454

      # Create a TCP server (socket type: SOCK_STREAM)
      server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_server, _ip, _port,family=socket.AF_INET, reuse_address=True)
      async with server: 
          await server.serve_forever()  

async def handle_server(reader, writer):
      # read data
      print("start reading")
      init_time = datetime.datetime.now()
      end_time = init_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
      while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:
          raw_data_stream = await reader.readexactly(200)
          print("time:", datetime.datetime.now()-init_time)

      # close connection
      writer.close()
      await writer.wait_closed()
      print("Connection closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(connect_to_sq())
```

The program is supposed to finish after 1 second data transmission. However, the output is:

```
start reading
time: 0:00:00.495863
time: 0:00:00.594812
time: 0:00:00.695760
time: 0:00:00.794883
time: 0:00:00.895336
time: 0:00:00.995024
time: 0:00:01.095308
Connection closed
start reading
time: 0:00:00.647908
time: 0:00:00.750355
time: 0:00:00.848436
......
```

It repeated automatically and infinitely. What is the reason for this and How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

`serve_forever()` listens to the port indefinitely. So, even though the individual connections close after 1 second, the server keeps accepting new connections. In this case, your sensor (client) seems to be creating a new connection after an old connection is closed, and since the server still accepts them, `handle_server` runs again from the top.

## Solution

Maybe not the best way™, but one possible solution is to use a `Future` so that `handle_server` can signal the main code upon connection completion. The main code can then stop the server, avoiding new connections. This is how it can be done:

```py
import datetime
import asyncio
import socket
from functools import partial

async def connect_to_sq():
      _ip = "0.0.0.0"
      _port = 45454

      # Create a TCP server (socket type: SOCK_STREAM)
      first_connection_completion = asyncio.Future()
      server = await asyncio.start_server(
        partial(handle_server, first_connection_completion=first_connection_completion),
        _ip,
        _port,family=socket.AF_INET,
        reuse_address=True)
      async with server: 
          server_task = asyncio.create_task(server.serve_forever())
          await first_connection_completion
          server_task.cancel()

async def handle_server(reader, writer, first_connection_completion=None):
      # read data
      print("start reading")
      init_time = datetime.datetime.now()
      end_time = init_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
      while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:
          raw_data_stream = await reader.readexactly(200)
          print("time:", datetime.datetime.now()-init_time)

      # close connection
      writer.close()
      await writer.wait_closed()
      print("Connection closed")
      first_connection_completion.set_result(None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(connect_to_sq())
```

Couple of notes:

- `handle_server` now takes one extra argument, `first_connection_completion` which is the future used to send signal from the function to the main code. The argument has been *binded* to the function using `functools.partial`. Within the function, `set_result` has been used to mark the future as completed.
- `serve_forever()` is now wrapped by a `create_task` call. This is because we can't `await` on it.

The new code looks messy, but you can always refactor. So a cleaner version would be:

```py
import datetime
import asyncio
import socket

async def listen_once(handler, *server_args, **server_kwargs):
    first_connection_completion = asyncio.Future()
    async def wrapped_handler(*args):
        await handler(*args)
        first_connection_completion.set_result(None)
    server = await asyncio.start_server(wrapped_handler, *server_args, **server_kwargs)
    async with server:
        server_task = asyncio.create_task(server.serve_forever())
        await first_connection_completion
        server_task.cancel()

async def connect_to_sq():
      _ip = "0.0.0.0"
      _port = 45454

      # Create a TCP server (socket type: SOCK_STREAM)
      await listen_once(handle_server, _ip, _port, family=socket.AF_INET, reuse_address=True)

async def handle_server(reader, writer):
      # read data
      print("start reading")
      init_time = datetime.datetime.now()
      end_time = init_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
      while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:
          raw_data_stream = await reader.readexactly(200)
          print("time:", datetime.datetime.now()-init_time)

      # close connection
      writer.close()
      await writer.wait_closed()
      print("Connection closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(connect_to_sq())
```